# Java jLayer GUI Application freezes while playing the music

Tags: java, swing, jlayer

I'm working on a Java project that requires background music so I'm using jLayer (MP3 library for the Java Platform) for better applicability and performance for my project.

I need to play the music with the help of `JFileChooser` so that the user can easily run own music from the menu bar.

But the whole GUI application freezes whenever I'm trying to run the any random music.

[Here's the code snippet of my Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6bjw.png)

[This is the Image of the Menubar where "Choose your own Music" is added as the Menu Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5S9L.png)

Can anyone please help me fixing me this code?

Comment: The most likely cause is the same cause that would freeze any GUI - You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread. The problem is so common you should have been able to find endless questions on the subject - The solution is always the same, don't do anything on the EDT that takes a long time or is blocking in any way. The method you use will depend on what you want to achieve. You could roll your own `Thread` or use a `SwingWorker`

Comment: `Here's the code snippet of my Application` - don't post an image of your code. When you ask a question post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the reply 

Actually I'm new to the concept of _Multithreading_ & _Concurrency_ right now

Can you please explain how and where i can implement _SwingWorker_ in my Java Application

Comment: @camickr i'm sorry i'd surely take care of that next time

Comment: @ChetanNautiyal, `Can you please explain how and where i can implement SwingWorker in my Java Application` - I already gave you that answer 17 hours ago. Read the tutorial!!!

Comment: Problem has been finally solved :D
Thanks @MadProgrammer for the big help bro :)

Answer (score 2):

> The whole GUI application freezes whenever i'm trying to run the any random Music from the menu bar with the help of "JFileChooser"

Code executed from a listener is executed on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. This Thread is responsible for responding to events and repainting the GUI. If you execute a long task (like playing music) then the GUI can't respond to events.

You need to start your music player on a separate `Thread`. One way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker` which provides additional functionality which is helpful when using Swing.

Read the tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.